# Proving the number of steps in Merge Sort algorithm based on a recurrence

Tags: algorithms, induction, computer-science, recursive-algorithms

> This is for a sorting algorithm (Merge Sort), where $T$ represents the maximum number of steps executed by the algorithm. $n$ represents the length of the input array (to be sorted) and $k$ represents a threshold, where if $n \le k$, a different algorithm is used to sort which takes $\alpha n^2 + \beta n + \delta$ steps.

If we have a function $T : \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $\forall$ positive integers $n$ and $k$,

$$
T(n,k) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \alpha n^2 + \beta n + \delta & \quad \text{if }\; n \le k \\
            T(\lceil n / 2 \rceil, k) + T(\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor, k) + \gamma n + \zeta & \quad \text{if }\; n > k \\
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

And if we know the following:

- $\alpha, \beta, \gamma > 0$
- $\delta + \gamma + \zeta > 0$
- $A = \text{max} \biggl( \alpha + \beta + \delta + \zeta + \gamma, \; k * \alpha + \beta + \frac{1}{k} * (\delta + \zeta + \gamma) \biggr)$
- $B = -(\zeta + \gamma)$

Then we want to prove that

$$T(n,k) \le \gamma n \text{ log}_2 n + An + B$$

for every positive integer $n$.

I thought that maybe I could do proof by induction to prove this. However, then would I have to induct on both conditionals for $T(n,k)$ where I take into account both $n \le k$ and $n > k$? Also, I would assume that I would induct on $n$, but then $k$ remains an unknown variable? Or is induction just not the way to prove this?

I am also confused given the amount of unknown constants in the equations.

Comment: Yes you want to use two cases: $n\le k$ and $n>k$. Giving it a quick look, I'd say $An\le Ak$ should essentially cover the $n\le k$ case though.

Comment: Yeah, I think the $n \le k$ case is the easiest to prove. Not sure how to induct on $T(\lceil n / 2 \rceil, k) + T(\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor, k) + \gamma n + \zeta$ though. I think I would have to use closed form?

Comment: Use constructive induction.