# Getting a closed form of this recurrence

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, closed-form, recursion

Asked this before, but could not seem to get an answer. As such, I've simplified my question a bit.

> We have the following recurrence $T$:
>   $$
> T(n,k) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             \alpha n^2 + \beta n + \delta & \quad \text{if }\; n \le k \\
>             T(\lceil n / 2 \rceil, k) + T(\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor, k) + \gamma n + \zeta & \quad \text{if }\; n > k \\
>         \end{array}
>     \right.
> $$
>
> for all positive integers $n$ and $k$

I want to find a closed-form of $T$. The closest I have is:

$$\gamma n\text{log }_2(n)+2n - \zeta$$

but is not correct as it does not work for all positive integers $n$.

I am really confused on how to get a closed form or summation for $T$.

Comment: Please, give a reference to your previous question. It is the less you can do, because a lack of answer is not a reason for asking again and filling this site with useless duplicated, triplicated... questions (consider for example to erase your previous question)

Comment: I already deleted the previous question, but more context for this question is provided here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453914/proving-the-number-of-steps-in-merge-sort-algorithm-based-on-a-recurrence

Comment: For powers of $2$ it's not hard to get an exact solution. For general $n$ it is not hard to use this exact solution to get a big $\Theta$ estimate. I suspect finding an exact solution for non powers of $2$ will be quite difficult, though :/ If these estimates are good enough for your purposes, let me know and I'll write up a real answer.